# Getting Error 'Shape of passed values is (8708, 27), indices imply (8708, 4)' while applying OneHotEncoder on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am practicing OneHotEncoder on a dataframe sampled below:

```
datetime    season  holiday workingday  weather         temp    atemp   humidity    windspeed   Total_booking   Hour    weekday    Month    date

5/2/2012 19:00  Summer  0   1       Clear + Few clouds  22.14   25.76   77          16.9979          504         19     Wednesday   May     5/2/2012

9/5/2012 4:00   Fall    0   1       Clear + Few clouds  28.7    33.335  79          19.0012         5           4       Wednesday  September9/5/2012
```

**Code:**

'df' is the dataframe that is sampled above. 'categoryVariableList' is a list of columns in the dataframe(df) that needs to be used for OneHotEncoder.

```
categoryVariableList = ["weekday","Month","season","weather"]

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
feature_arr = ohe.fit_transform(df[categoryVariableList]).toarray()
feature_labels = ohe.categories_

feature_labels = np.array(feature_labels).ravel()

features = pd.DataFrame(feature_arr, columns=feature_labels)
features
```

The **Output** I get is as followed:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 27, placement implies 4
.....
Shape of passed values is (8708, 27), indices imply (8708, 4)
```

What is going wrong here? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your `feature_arr` has 27 column but `feature_labels` is just 4 columns, so creating `pandas.DataFrame` failed .

You could use `.get_feature_names()`

```
categoryVariableList = ["weekday","Month","season","weather"]

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
feature_arr = ohe.fit_transform(df[categoryVariableList]).toarray()
feature_labels = ohe.get_feature_names(categoryVariableList)

# feature_labels = np.array(feature_labels).ravel()

features = pd.DataFrame(feature_arr, columns=feature_labels)
features
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use Label Encoder instead

df_x[categorical_cols_x] = df_x[categorical_cols_x].apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
df_x[categorical_cols_x]